# Reducing a pandas dataframe by keeping nth largest values

Tags: pandas

Let say I have the follwing dataframe:

```
id1    dt                   id2   count
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id0   78
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id1   79
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id2   80
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id3   69
0      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id4   58
1      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id0   67
```

I want to keep for each "dt" the nth most "id2" that are selected by the higher "count".
Hence obtaining, for nth=3:

```
id1    dt                   id2   count
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id0   78
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id1   79
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id2   80
0      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id4   58
1      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id0   67
```

It should also detect multiple "id2". Hence if input is:

```
id1    dt                   id2   count
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id0   78
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id1   79
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id2   80
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id2   79
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id3   69
0      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id4   58
1      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id0   67
```

It must return for nth=3

```
id1    dt                   id2   count
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id0   78
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id1   79
0      2010-02-06 07:21:45  id2   80
0      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id4   58
1      2010-02-06 07:58:25  id0   67
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df = df.sort_values("count", ascending=False).groupby(["dt", "id2"], as_index=False).first()
df = df.groupby("dt").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0:3]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Almost exactly what I was looking for. I had to do 
`d.sort_values('count', ascending=False).groupby(['dt', 'id1', 'id2']).first().reset_index(drop=False).sort_values('count', ascending=False).groupby(['dt', 'id1']).nth([0,1,2]).reset_index(drop=False) `.
Note that nth is far more faster than the apply.

Comment: oh cool - `nlargest()` also exists and may be even more succinct, performant